# C# SerialPort name not recognized

Tags: c#, serial-port

So here is the thing. I got the port names from the SerialPort.GetPortNames() function, however if I try to initialize my serialport I get a compiler error saying "name com4 not found". My ports however are called com4 and com1, so it should find them.

Here is my code example:

```
class Schnittstelle{
    SerialPort comPort = new SerialPort(COM4, 55670); //baudrate: 115200
    public string oeffnePort(){           
        if (comPort.IsOpen == false){
            comPort.Open();
            return null;
        }else if (comPort.BytesToRead != 0){
            return comPort.ReadExisting();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `COM4` in your code? Please show declaration and initialization.

Comment: Is COM4 a string that contains "COM4"? Take care of caps, I mean that COM4 is different from com4.

Comment: COM4 is an incredibly illogical name for a variable that stores a port name.  It is so nonsensical that the C# compiler even won't put up with it :)  Use something like string portName = SerialPort.GetPortNames[0];

Comment: Thanks i think i got it now!

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this issue with some virtual COM port drivers (not FTDI). COM port shows up in Device Manager, but cannot be accessed.
It helped me to just restart the computer after the driver was installed.

Comment: I tried that, but it did not work. Do I have to declare the name of my port somewhere? I just used Com4 because I assumed it would find it automatically.

Comment: Yes, in your case you do, see Hans Passant's comment above and use that.